# Table containing the count of multiple columns?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I've got the following table:

| Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | a | b |
| b | a | c |
| a | c | e |
| c | b | e |
| a | d | a |

How do I create a pivot table (or something similar) containing the count of answers per question?
i.e. something like the following:

| Value | Question 1 Count | Question 2 Count | Question 3 Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| b | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| c | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| d | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| e | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Creating it with one Column is easy enough, however I can't figure out how to do it with multiple columns because libreoffice will start stacking the rows/columns.

I'd appreciate any help or nudge in the right direction.

I tried creating a pivot table containing multiple rows/columns. I've already tried it by selecting my questions and putting them all in row or column, however libreoffice will start stacking them, creating subcolumns/rows without the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a makeshift solution.
It's basically the following somewhere else in the sheet:

| Value | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$122;"a")` | `=COUNTIF(B$2:B$122;"a")` | `=COUNTIF(C$2:C$122;"a")` |
| b | `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$122;"b")` | `=COUNTIF(B$2:B$122;"b")` | `=COUNTIF(C$2:C$122;"b")` |
| c | `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$122;"c")` | `=COUNTIF(B$2:B$122;"c")` | `=COUNTIF(C$2:C$122;"c")` |

not the most beautiful solution but it works for now. I'd appreciate a better one though.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `"a"` it would be easier to reference the `Value` column instead, which contains `a` for the first row. That way, the formulas could easily be filled. Once that is done, this looks like a perfectly acceptable solution — easier to set up than a pivot table I would think, and it may not be worth taking too much time to look for a different way. But if you decide to dig deeper, queries could do this after moving the data into Base, something like `SELECT VALUE, COUNT(*) FROM QUESTIONS GROUP BY VALUE`.